# SQL Server - recursive DATEADD query

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I get the following query give me the same date for the last N years?

```
declare @step int = 0;
declare @datobserve date = '2021-11-03';

with dates as 
(
select dateadd(year, @step, @datobserve) datobserve, @step step
union all
select dateadd(year, step, datobserve) as datobserve, step - 1
from dates
where 1=1
--and step = step + 1
and step > -4
)
select * from dates
```

The result I am getting is:

[image]

instead of:

[image]

Comment: A Tally or Calendar Table would be a far better option than an rCTE.

Comment: Change the recursive member of the query: 1)`@datobserve`, instead of `datobserve` and 2)`step-1` instead of `step`.

Comment: Also make sure you are happy with whatever happens if `2020-02-29` is the anchor date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you know it's only a handful of rows, like 5, I find it simpler to not bother with recursion:

```
DECLARE @datobserve date = '20211103';

;WITH n(n) AS 
(
  SELECT n FROM (VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(5)) AS n(n)
)
SELECT datobserve = DATEADD(YEAR, 1-n, @datobserve), step = 1-n 
FROM n
ORDER BY datobserve DESC;
```

If the list is larger or variable, I still like to get the *numbers* part recursively, and work the dates around that output:

```
DECLARE @steps      int  = 5,
        @datobserve date = '20211103';

;WITH n(n) AS 
(
  SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT n+1 FROM n WHERE n < @steps
)
SELECT datobserve = DATEADD(YEAR, 1-n, @datobserve), step = 1-n 
FROM n
ORDER BY datobserve DESC;
```

- Examples @ [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=78ed1f38739e2e276c5aa1ca3186eff5)

Comment: This is great, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to find the errors in your *... recursive DATEADD query ...* and get the *... same date for the last N years ...*, you need to make two changes in the recursive member of your statement:

- Use `@datobserve` instead of `datobserve`
- Use `step - 1` instead of `step`

Statement:

```
declare @step int = 0;
declare @n int = 4;
declare @datobserve date = '2021-11-03';

with dates as 
(
   select dateadd(year, @step, @datobserve) datobserve, @step step
   union all
   select dateadd(year, step - 1, @datobserve) as datobserve, step - 1
   from dates
   where step > -@n
)
select * 
from dates
option (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

Result:

```
datobserve  step
2021-11-03  0
2020-11-03  -1
2019-11-03  -2
2018-11-03  -3
2017-11-03  -4
```

Answer (score 2):

Just another option using an ad-hoc tally table

**Example**

```
Declare @Years int = 4
Declare @Date date ='2021-11-03'

Select dateobserve = dateadd(year,N,@Date)
      ,Step = N
 From ( Select Top (@Years+1) N=1-Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select NULL)) 
          From master..spt_values n1
      ) NT
```

**Results**

```
dateobserve Step
2021-11-03  0
2020-11-03  -1
2019-11-03  -2
2018-11-03  -3
2017-11-03  -4
```